# sql - how to sum a dynamically created column with the same id?

Tags: sql

```
select 
    Cu.CustomerNum, Cu.Name, sum(Cio1.Quantity * C1.Price) AS Total_Income
from 
    Orders O1 
inner join 
    CoursesInOrder Cio1 on O1.OrderNum = Cio1.OrderNum
inner join 
    Customer Cu on Cu.CustomerNum = O1.CustomerNum
inner join 
    Course C1 on C1.CourseNum = Cio1.CourseNum
where 
    O1.CustomerNum in (select O.CustomerNum
                       from Course C 
                       inner join CoursesInOrder Cio on C.CourseNum = Cio.CourseNum 
                       inner join Orders O on O.OrderNum= Cio.OrderNum 
                       where C.CourseNum = '99771'  
                         and year(O.Shiftdate) = '2014' 
                       group by O.CustomerNum
                       having count(O.CustomerNum) > 2)
```

[Current output]

[image: 1]

[Wanted output][image: 2]

I'm trying to sum the dynamically created solumn - Total_Income,
it keeps giving me almost-random errors,
would appreciate any help!

Comment: You need to use GROUP BY with aggregates such as SUM.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    Cu.CustomerNum, Cu.Name, sum(Cio1.Quantity * C1.Price) AS Total_Income
from 
    Orders O1 
inner join 
    CoursesInOrder Cio1 on O1.OrderNum = Cio1.OrderNum
inner join 
    Customer Cu on Cu.CustomerNum = O1.CustomerNum
inner join 
    Course C1 on C1.CourseNum = Cio1.CourseNum
where 
    O1.CustomerNum in (select O.CustomerNum
                       from Course C 
                       inner join CoursesInOrder Cio on C.CourseNum = Cio.CourseNum 
                       inner join Orders O on O.OrderNum= Cio.OrderNum 
                       where C.CourseNum = '99771'  
                         and year(O.Shiftdate) = '2014' 
                       group by O.CustomerNum
                       having count(O.CustomerNum) > 2)
Group by Cu.CustomerNum, Cu.Name
```

Comment: You are my man!!!!
Thank you very much brother, helped me a lot.